# Unable to create record through LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

I have been trying to create an account record through LWC but I am unable to do so. Can anyone identify the issue here. Please find the code snippet below:

**Markup:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Create Account</h2>
        </div>
        <lightning-layout>    
            <lightning-layout-item size = "6" padding="around-medium">
                <div >
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Account Name" onchange={accountNameHandler}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="phone" label="Account Phone" onchange={accountPhoneHandler}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="url" label="Account Website" onchange={accountWebsiteHandler}></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Create Account" onclick={createAccount}></lightning-button>
                </div>    
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class AccountManager extends LightningElement {
        @track accountName;
        @track accountPhone;
        @track accountWebsite;        

        accountNameHandler(event){
            this.accountName = event.target.value;
        }
        accountPhoneHandler(event){
            this.accountPhone = event.target.value;
        }
        accountWebsiteHandler(event){
            this.accountWebsite = event.target.value;
        }
        
        createAccount(){
            const fieldValues = {'Name' : this.accountName, 'Phone' : this.accountPhone, 'Website' : this.accountWebsite};
            const recordInput = {apiName : 'Account', fieldValues};

            createRecord(recordInput).then(response => {
            console.log('Account created with Id:', response.id);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Error Message', error.body.message);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to do so"? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Yes, in the console it says, 'Error Message An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.' @TSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the structure of `recordInput` is incorrect. You must define the structure like

```
{
  "apiName": "Account",
  "fields": {
    "Name": "Universal Containers"
  }
}
```

Key naming is important and in this is the reason for your failure to insert a new Account. Modify `fieldValues` to `fields`.

Also, you do not need to use `@track` decorator as event handlers are taking care of DOM updates communicating to JS.

Comment: Updated the code as you have mentioned and it's working fine
           
 const recordInput = {'apiName' : 'Account', 'fields' : fieldValues};

Thanks @TSmith